# Replacing Text of Content Controls in OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, word-contentcontrol

I have a word file that have multy `Rich Text Content Control` I want to change text of it. I Use this code .

```
 using (WordprocessingDocument theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docName, true))
 {
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart;
    foreach (SdtElement sdt in mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>())
    {
        SdtAlias alias = sdt.Descendants<SdtAlias>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (alias != null)
        {
            string sdtTitle = alias.Val.Value;
            var t = sdt.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault();
            t.Text="Atul works at Microsoft as a .NET consultant. As a consultant his job is to design, develop and deploy";
        }
    }
 }
```

It is add new text with old text. But i want to `replace` this!!!

Comment: what are you wanting to replace it with.,.?

Comment: sdt have a Text that have a text with 70 char, when i set text it replace text with 20 char of Text . but i want to remove all 70 char and then replace text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only retrieve and update the first Text of your sdtContent.
To replace all of it, the simples way is:

- Delete all text
- Add the new text

Update your code with:

```
if (alias != null)
{
    // delete all paragraph of the sdt
    sdt.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList().ForEach(p => p.Remove());
    // insert your new text, who is composed of:
    // - A Paragraph
    // - A Run
    // - A Text
    sdt.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("As a consultant his job is to design, develop and love poney."))));
}
```

**edit:** I forget to add the paragraph and the run

You can see how is build a SdtContent here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.sdtcontentblock(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but i have a template file that every ContentControl have a format and i don't delete it. I want to Replace text.

Comment: Could you give your xml, before replacing the text and after replacing it

Comment: I do not understand your solution.

Comment: in openxml your text can be split in differents `<Text>`. The principe is to suppress all text and add your new one. It's a replace.
But it would be muuuuuch simpler if you share your xml (cause here, I propose a solution in the blind, and I can't assure it works like that without changes)

Comment: Thanks, i use this. `Text newText = new Text("value"); Run newRun = new Run();                                      newRun.Append(newText);sdt.Append(newRun);` but when open word i get error that don't open.

Comment: I edit the code, but once again, it would be really much simpler if you edit your question with an example of your xml

Comment: I use this but get error again. I use this `sdt.Descendants<Text>).ToList().ForEach(i =>                                            i.Text=string.Empty);` it is ok, but when value is empty, i get a break line. I want to remove this break line. How do i i?

Comment: " ... love poney " ?