# Insert multiple lines of text into a Rich Text content control with OpenXML

Tags: openxml, multiline, contentcontrol

I'm having difficulty getting a content control to follow multi-line formatting. It seems to interpret everything I'm giving it literally. I am new to OpenXML and I feel like I must be missing something simple.

I am converting my multi-line string using this function.

```
    private static void parseTextForOpenXML(Run run, string text)
    {
        string[] newLineArray = { Environment.NewLine, "<br/>", "<br />", "\r\n" };
        string[] textArray = text.Split(newLineArray, StringSplitOptions.None);

        bool first = true;

        foreach (string line in textArray)
        {
            if (!first)
            {
                run.Append(new Break());
            }

            first = false;

            Text txt = new Text { Text = line };
            run.Append(txt);
        }
    }
```

I insert it into the control with this

```
    public static WordprocessingDocument InsertText(this WordprocessingDocument doc, string contentControlTag, string text)
    {
        SdtElement element = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().FirstOrDefault(sdt => sdt.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == contentControlTag);

        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("ContentControlTag " + contentControlTag + " doesn't exist.");

        element.Descendants<Text>().First().Text = text;
        element.Descendants<Text>().Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(t => t.Remove());

        return doc;
    }
```

I call it with something like...

```
doc.InsertText("Primary", primaryRun.InnerText);
```

Although I've tried InnerXML and OuterXML as well. The results look something like

Example AttnExample CompanyExample AddressNew York, NY 12345 or

```
<w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:t>Example Attn</w:t><w:br /><w:t>Example Company</w:t><w:br /><w:t>Example Address</w:t><w:br /><w:t>New York, NY 12345</w:t></w:r>
```

The method works fine for simple text insertion. It's just when I need it to interpret the XML that it doesn't work for me.

I feel like I must be super close to getting what I need, but my fiddling is getting me nowhere. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way I was trying to do it was doomed to fail. Setting the Text attribute of an element is always going to be interpreted as text to be displayed it seems. I ended up having to take a slightly different tack. I created a new insert method.

```
    public static WordprocessingDocument InsertText(this WordprocessingDocument doc, string contentControlTag, Paragraph paragraph)
    {
        SdtElement element = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().FirstOrDefault(sdt => sdt.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == contentControlTag);

        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("ContentControlTag " + contentControlTag + " doesn't exist.");

        OpenXmlElement cc = element.Descendants<Text>().First().Parent;
        cc.RemoveAllChildren();
        cc.Append(paragraph);

        return doc;
    }
```

It starts the same, and gets the Content Control by searching for it's Tag. But then I get it's parent, remove the Content Control elements that were there and just replace them with a paragraph element.

It's not exactly what I had envisioned, but it seems to work for my needs.

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing the answer, how did  you convert carriage returned type text into Paragraph?

Comment: I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31755783/5955233 but it gives me corrupted docx file.

Comment: in my original question I show a ParseTextForOpenXML method that does what you're asking, I think.

Comment: and about your own answer as well. How to add multiline text in CC when you have carriage returns in text passed to the method WordprocessingDocument?

Comment: I've seen somewhere a tag `<w:br/>` https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9d352a11-ad84-4099-8847-ded678125f6e/display-cutom-xml-text-in-multiple-lines-inside-a-rich-text-content-control-in-word-2007?forum=oxmlsdk it should advice Word to add a new line